# Sublime plugins execute in docker container

Tags: docker, sublimetext

I'm new to Docker so I'm not sure if I have missed something basic here. I like the idea of having various development platforms in different Docker containers to keep my host box relatively clean. I see that this is possible but in most examples it involves people using vim once ssh'd into the container to edit code. I wanted to use sublime, I know I can map a volume allowing me to edit the source code outside of the container. The part I can't see how I can configure is support for plugins, for example GoSublime runs tools like GoCode. Is it possible to have these tools executed inside the container, whilst Sublime is running in the host?

thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't run Sublime _and_ the plugins in the container?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is not, I was not sure if there was an alternative that is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If the editor is in a container, it should be able to execute most binaries (there are some limitations such as not requiring certain unsafe permissions that allows the guest to break out easily).

If you want the editor to execute tools installed within a container, the editor itself will need to support starting them using docker.

For the first use case, you'll want to make sure any tools you want to run are installed within the container and not just in your host. The container is isolated, so it will not automatically have access to tools installed on your host. Take a look at https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/ to see how you can build custom images.

Comment: Thanks. I see there are two ways to run a gui app in a container, either bind the Unix x port from guest to host or x-forward over ssh. I'll give them a try.

Comment: I've developed http://dockershell.io/ for this purpose, but it currently doesn't support X applications. It shouldn't be hard to add, though. It does, however support ssh key forwarding and access to docker from *inside* the docker shell container.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of Sublime's plugin architecture is that they're installed per-user, not for the whole system. They're more like configuration.

You should probably have a volume for your configuration anyway, not just the source. Plugins are just a part of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can now:

Docker published the images of top programming languages, and is leveraged by this plugin - Docker based build systems created by http://domeide.github.io

- Install the package using the package manager
- Select your build system
- Ctrl-B(Win/Linux) or Cmd-B (OSX) to execute your code